# (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: WorkGroup is not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, workgroup

While firing a

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

in Athena, I am getting a

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: WorkGroup is not found.
```

I checked the workgroup with which the query is being fired and it is present and active. (attached image below)

[image]

I am expecting the table to be created. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in the setup wherein the wrong AWS credentials were being setup.
Closing this question for the same.